# Google - will they penalize you for random content ordering?

Tags: google, seo

A client of mine wants to have their work ordered randomly on the website each time you load the page. My concern is that Google will see this as an effort to try and trick it into changing content which is not the intention. Please advise anyone with any experience of this, there don't seem to be any clean cut answers.

I've mentioned the issues with UX familiarity and it being a bizarre behavior but it is still somewhat desired.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "their work"?

Comment: I guess he means something like this http://softkube.com/portfolio/ where the order is not by date or by importance but rather random every time you access the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you find an answer today then maybe a Google policy update will put you in trouble zone so why take the risk.

I suggest you tackle the problem differently. Always display your content in the same order inside your HTML and do order it randomly via JavaScript or jQuery dynamically.

Good luck.

Comment: Managed to persuade the client to have their work structured in a more logical fashion through UX reasoning. :)

Comment: Another method I have used before is to order them randomly but keep that order for a day at a time. (If the items come from a database you could add an order field that you update daily with new random numbers.)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat yes and this is exactly what will cause the issue we're trying to solve. Matthew3man that was the best way to go. Good luck. Cheers!